# View that add items to nested list within nested list

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a fairly simple example model that contains a list, which also contains a list.

```
// Main object ... 1
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // 0..*
    public IList<Item> Items { get; set;}

}

public class Item 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // 0..*
    public IList<SubItem> SubItems {get;set;}
}

public class SubItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With these model classes, I would like to create a view which allow to dynamically **add items and sub-items**.

Example:

[image: example]

I have read a lot about this, but there does not seem to be a common method to perform what I want to do. There are lots of examples of a list within an object, but none about a list within a list within an object.

Is there a way to do what I want to do? Or do I absolutely need to separate my views?

**What I've tried** :

- EditorTemplate (It works for my items list, but I can't add items to my SubItems list)
- EditorFor (model => model.SubItems)
- Add items with jQuery but I don't think it's the right way to do this.

Thanks,

S.H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but the tricky part is getting the id's of your nested view controls to play nicely with the MVC model binder.

I've got this to work in the past by using the instructions detailed here -->  http://mleeb.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/editing-nested-lists-in-asp-mvc-4/